# Creating a SQL View for full month when table only includes past days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I'm hoping to create a view in a SQL Server database. It will be based on one table which looks like this:

```
Date (primary key) | Minimum (decimal) | Target (decimal) | Achieved (decimal)
```

As a month progresses, e.g. January 2015, that table will be populated daily.

I want to create a view which looks like this (say we are only up to 2nd January 2015):

```
2015-01-01 | Minimum | Target | Achieved | Calculated Column

2015-01-02 | Minimum | Target | Achieved | Calculated Column

2015-01-03 | null    | null   | null     | Calculated Column

...

2015-01-31 | null    | null   | null     | Calculated Column
```

So, essentially returning data from the table where available but then also adding a row for each future day too. Don't worry about the calculated column, I think I can do that bit.

Does that makes sense? Grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a calendar table which has all dates in the ranges of interest for it.  Then you just join to that table with a condition on the month.  See [this web site](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/) on how to make a calendar table.  There are many ways to do it.

Edit: Per this [site](http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/07/generating-temporary-calendar-tables.html), you could use a CTE before your query to create a temporary calendar to join to:

```
declare @start datetime,
@end datetime

set @start = '2006-01-01'
set @end = '2007-01-01'
;
with calendar(date,isweekday, y, q,m,d,dw,monthname,dayname,w) as
(
select @start ,
case when datepart(dw,@start) in (1,7) then 0 else 1 end,
year(@start),
datepart(qq,@start),
datepart(mm,@start),
datepart(dd,@start),
datepart(dw,@start),
datename(month, @start),
datename(dw, @start),
datepart(wk, @start)
union all
select date + 1,
case when datepart(dw,date + 1) in (1,7) then 0 else 1 end,
year(date + 1),
datepart(qq,date + 1),
datepart(mm,date + 1),
datepart(dd,date + 1),
datepart(dw,date + 1),
datename(month, date + 1),
datename(dw, date + 1),
datepart(wk, date + 1) from calendar where date + 1< @end
)
select * from calendar option(maxrecursion 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, apparently you need to use a stored procedure or a function since your output must have an end date. So basically, you need a stored procedure or function that accepts a date parameter and outputs a table containing the data you want. Something similar to the following may help:

```
USE TEST -- Test database. You may want to replace this with your DB name
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE proStackOverflowQuestion25287207 @date date -- To try it, execute: exec proStackOverflowQuestion25287207 '2008-02-11' -- or any date of your choice.
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @monthdays INT, @dateday INT, @marker INT, @noRecordDate NVARCHAR(30)
    SET @marker = 1 -- we start the first day of the month         
    SET @monthdays = DATEDIFF(dd,@date,(DATEADD(mm,1,@date))) -- get the number of days in the concerned month
    SET @dateday = DAY(@date)

    CREATE TABLE #temTbl(
        [Date] [date] PRIMARY KEY,
        [Minimum] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
        [Target] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
        [Achieved] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
        [Calculated] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
        )

    WHILE @marker <= @monthdays
        BEGIN
    --insert new record in temp table
            IF exists(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DAY([Date]) = @marker AND MONTH([Date]) = MONTH(@date) AND YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(@date))
            INSERT INTO #temTbl SELECT *, null FROM MyTable WHERE DAY([Date]) = @marker --*** you may need to replace null by your Calculated value...
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @noRecordDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), YEAR(@date)) + '-' +  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), MONTH(@date)) + '-' +  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), @marker)
                INSERT INTO #temTbl([Date], Minimum, [Target], Achieved, Calculated) VALUES (@noRecordDate, null, null, null, null) -- you may need to replace the last null by your calculated value...
            END

            -- increment marker
            SET @marker = @marker + 1
        END

SELECT * FROM #temTbl

END
```